# Is it necessary to put my full name on my Linkedin profile?

Tags: linkedin, networking, privacy

I want to create a Linkedin profile but I don't like to share my personal and anagraphic data publicly: as far as I know Linkedin shares generic personal info (i.e. profile picture, full name and city) to anyone in the network, even when she/he is not among user's contacts.

I would like to avoid writing my full name, I would like to write an abbreviation of my name followed by my surname and I want to avoid putting my picture; on the other hands, those info will be inserted on the curricula vitae I will send to find a job.
Therefore my question is:

Might it be a bad practice omitting the complete name and the picture on a Linkedin profile?

Comment: Many people don't have profile pictures at all. In your privacy settings you can set it so that only your contacts can see your last name. There are probably a number of other settings there you would find useful.

Comment: Why bother?....

Comment: The point of Linkedin is to publicly share your information.

Comment: I've yet to have found or received a useful contact from Linked in.

Comment: What is your intended use case for the LinkedIn profile? If you don’t put your last name, people probably won’t be able to find your profile unless you give them the URL. But maybe that’s what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Might it be a bad practice omitting the complete name and the picture on a Linkedin profile?

Omitting your picture may or may not be a problem -- in US business culture, people rarely include their pictures on resumes.

Not using your full name, however, can work against you. It's common practice to use your full name, so people looking at your profile might incorrectly assume you are hiding something.

The point of being on LinkedIn (I presume) is to be found. You will simply be harder to find without your name. If you have any mentions or credits anywhere, people will naturally try to look you up, and won't be able to locate your profile.

People who search LinkedIn often do so with a location filter, so you may be missing opportunities if you don't provide geographical information.

One alternative is to list on LinkedIn a slightly different name than you usually use -- maybe a nickname, or your full legal name. That way you can still be found, but you'll know the contact isn't personal by the way they address you.

Comment: Regarind the first sentence, you should state your region. In my country, CVs without picture are strange and will probably not considered for application (except maybe in academia).

Comment: @guest -- thanks, I have edited to be more specific. What country are you from?

Comment: I am from Middle Europe (sorry, I don't want to be more specific). Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @guest not a problem, I totally understand. Thanks again!